# Check if readonly file input is empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with an input type and a file browse and I need to enable he confirm button only if both are valid (not empty text and one file selected).
This is HTML code:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
  <!-- form start -->
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="45" placeholder="Version name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Note </label>(optional)
      <textarea id="note" class="form-control" rows="4" maxlength="255"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn"> <span
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-file" id="browseButton"> Browse&hellip; <input
                        id="versionFile" type="file" name="file" />
                </span>
      </span>
      <input id="versionName" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button id="uploadVersionButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload version</button>
</div>
```

As you can see the file input text is readonly and i have difficult to check it. I thought to check if name input is not empty when a file is selected, but

```
$('#versionName').bind('change',validate);
```

the validate function

```
    function validate() {
   if($('#name').val().length > 0) {
     var fileControl = document.getElementById('versionFile');
     if(fileControl.files.length === 0) {
       $("#uploadVersionButton").prop("disabled", true);
       notifyMessage("Your file is empty!", 'error');
     } else {
       $("#uploadVersionButton").prop("disabled", false);
     }
   } else {
     notifyMessage("Please insert a name for the client version.", 'error');
     $("#uploadVersionButton").prop("disabled", true);
   }
 }
```

doesn't work on readonly field. Do you have idea to check this two field?

Comment: On which event you want to invoke `validate` function ?

Comment: maybe I have to invoke validate function on $('#name').keyup(validate); and on file input change

Comment: Then do so.. What is not working ? You could try [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event too

Comment: I can't trigger the file input change

Comment: The change event needs to be on the file input then not some text input

Comment: It should be like this right ? `$('#versionFile').bind('change',validate); ` as `versionFile` is the `id` for `file` input..

Comment: I was using versionName and not versionFile, it was a stupid error. If you answer this question I can accept it